# Getting missing separator when invoking make

Tags: c, makefile

I am writing a simple makefile to compile my program, with sources in `src` folder and headers in `inc` folder, but I am getting the error

```
src/test1.c:3: *** missing separator,Stop
```

I've read a few posts here about that error and everyone said it's because of putting spaces instead of tabs before the commands. **I am 100 % certain that I am using tabs**, but the error remains... Here's the makefile

```
SOURCE = $(wildcard src/*.c)
OBJECTS = $(SOURCE:.o=.c)
DEBS = $(SOURCE:.d=.c)

-include $(DEBS)

all:$(OBJECTS)
    gcc -o asd.exe $(OBJECTS)

%.o:%.c
    gcc -c $< 

%.d:%.c
    gcc -o $@ -MM $< 

.PHONY:clean

clean:
    rm -f *.c
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TABs vs spaces is (in this case) a red herring.  Your error message shows the problem:

```
src/test1.c:3: *** missing separator,Stop.
```

Hm... make is complaining about line 3 of the file `src/test1.c`... why is make parsing your C code!?!?

Here's why: you have your substitution backwards:

```
OBJECTS = $(SOURCE:.o=.c)
DEBS = $(SOURCE:.d=.c)
```

The first line replaces all `xxx.o` paths with `xxx.c`.  That's the exact opposite of what you want: you want to replace all the `xxx.c` paths with `xxx.o`.  Ditto for the `.d` files.

Since no substitutions happen, the unmodified files are left so the value of the `DEBS` variable is `src/test1.c`, etc. then you try to `include` that as a makefile.

Fix your assignments:

```
OBJECTS = $(SOURCE:.c=.o)
DEBS = $(SOURCE:.c=.d)
```

**Tip:**

It's much more efficient to use simple assignment here:

```
SOURCE := $(wildcard src/*.c)
OBJECTS := $(SOURCE:.c=.o)
DEBS := $(SOURCE:.c=.d)
```

Comment: That worked i don't get that error anymore.Thank you so much.